# how to prevent deletion of node if it has no objects under it

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

For this picture if I delete the child 465656 in the app haab node is also deleted.
How can I prevent this ?

Comment: Why don't you want it to be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `haab` node will always be deleted (removed) if you delete the `465656` node or any other child node of `haab`, **IF** the `465656` node or any other similar child node is the **ONLY CHILD NODE** of `haab`.

In Firebase Realtime Database, any parent node that has no child node is automatically deleted.

In order to prevent this, instead of deleting the `465656` node or any other **ONLY CHILD** node, you could replace it with the number itself.

So, instead of setting the value of the `465656` node to `null` or using the `.remove()` method (for web), you could use a `.update()` (for web) to convert the object to just `465656` or you could use the `.set()` (for web) or `.setValue()` for Java/Android on the `465656` node to replace the `465656` node obeject with just 465656`